# function returns one row from QUERY postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Hello to everyone i am new to postgresql and I have a specific question. I am trying to create a function which when I run it to sql editor, everything is fine and i get the expected result. So this is the code that i run to sql editor:

```
SELECT  email,count(*) 
FROM article
GROUP BY email
HAVING count(*)>=2;
```

But when i try to write this on a function and run the function on sql editor, it returns me only the first row of the result.Also i have clicked in the box on option Return set .I tried to create some loops in order to access the results but it didn't work. Here is the function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test()
  RETURNS TABLE(a character varying, b integer) AS
$BODY$


DECLARE ema CHARACTER VARYING;
DECLARE coun INTEGER;

BEGIN

CREATE TEMP TABLE exp(email CHARACTER VARYING,counter INTEGER);




SELECT  email,count(*) INTO ema,coun
FROM article
GROUP BY email
HAVING count(*)>=2;


INSERT INTO exp(email,counter) VALUES (ema,coun);

RETURN QUERY SELECT DISTINCT * FROM exp;
END;$BODY$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because you are returning a table doesnt mean you have to create one. Try it more simple:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test()
  RETURNS TABLE(a character varying, b integer) AS
$BODY$

BEGIN    
    RETURN QUERY 
         SELECT  email a , count(*) b
         FROM article
         GROUP BY email
         HAVING count(*)>=2;        
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Note you dont need `distinct` because you are already using `GROUP BY`